# Como adicionar class com javascript puro (sem jQuery)

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como fazer com que, quando o **segundo elemento** da primeira ul receber a classe ".active" a imagem de classe ".img2" receba uma classe do tipo "imagem-ativa" com javascript puro. Por gentileza.

Importante: Não basta selecionar apenas o elemento que tenha a classe .active, mas a ordem dele. Tipo: Selecionar o elemento 3 se ele tiver a classe .active.

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><img class="img1" src="#"/></li>
  <li><img class="img2" src="#"/></li>
  <li><img class="img3" src="#"/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: E qual é a condição para o elemento receber a classe `active`? Você já tem essa parte do código?

Comment: se o segundo elemento tiver a classe .active, por exemplo. Não sei nada de javascript. rs

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isto te ajuda:

```js
const itens = [...document.querySelectorAll('#menu li')];

const imagens = [...document.querySelectorAll('#imagens img')];

itens.forEach(i => {

  i.addEventListener('click', ev => selecionar(ev));

});

const selecionar = (ev) => {

  const t = ev.currentTarget;
  
  itens.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('active'));
  
  imagens.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('imagem-ativa'));
  
  t.classList.add('active');

  imagens[itens.indexOf(t)].classList.add('imagem-ativa');

};
```

```css
ul#menu li.active {
text-transform: uppercase;}

.imagem-ativa {border: 2px solid red;}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">service</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="imagens">
  <li><img class="img1" src="#"/></li>
  <li><img class="img2" src="#"/></li>
  <li><img class="img3" src="#"/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Em JavaScript puro você pode alterar a classe da seguinte forma:

```
var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("img2");
elementos[0].classList.add("imagem-ativa");
```